# How to notify changes to a row of p:dataTable which is currently being edited to a corresponding backing bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

How to know if contents of any column/s of the row being edited in a `<p:dataTable>` is changed? Given a simple example as follows.

The data table :

```
<p:dataTable var="brand" value="#{testManagedBean}"
             lazy="true" editable="true" rows="10">

    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{brand.brandId}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{brand.brandName}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{brand.brandName}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Edit" width="50">
        <p:rowEditor/>
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{testManagedBean.onRowEdit}"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

The managed bean  :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<Brand> implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private final TestBeanLocal service=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<Brand> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        setRowCount(3);  //Just an example. Actually fetched from the database.
        return service.getList(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        //Do something to check if the row currently being edited has been changed.
        //If something is changed then, invoke an EJB method to propagate changes to the database.
        //If nothing is changed then, get rid of invoking an expensive business service method to unnecessarily execute an update query.

        System.out.println("onRowEdit() called.");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to invoke business service (to update database contents) if and only if the row currently being edited in the given `<p:dataTable>` is actually changed?

<sub>There could be more columns in `<p:dataTable>` as and when required as obvious.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Add this property to the bean:

```
private Brand original;
```

In the dataTable, add a listener for a rowEditInit event:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{testManagedBean.onRowEditInit()}" />
```

Set the property value when the rowEditInit event is triggered:

```
public void onRowEditInit(RowEditEvent event) {
    original = (Brand) event.getObject();
}
```

Finally, do the checks in `onRowEdit()`:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    Brand modified = (Brand) event.getObject();
    // compare modified against original
}
```

Comment: This is awesome but it requires the `equals()` implementation to be changed in all associated entity classes. I genuinely hope that there should be another way to do so without comparing objects or their contents manually :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. Isn't this another question maybe?

Comment: It is somewhat tedious to manually compare individual properties of entity objects - `Brand` in this case especially when the object in question is too large/complex. Isn't it?

Comment: Either implement `equals()` on Brand class, or add ajax listeners for each input component used for editing (applying the same logic explained in my answer). Yes, they are both tedious ways, but I don't see other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I needed a way to access the new and old value for the column in the row I am editing, I created another variable in my dataTable backing bean to store the original value of the cell before it's edited as backup, using this technique. It's weird that rowEdit event does not tell you which column in the row is edited or what it's old value was directly, considering that cellEdit gives you the new and old values.